# function that prints counding down numbers and up but in a pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I already know how to count down and up using reccurssive function but I cant figure out how to define another function to have spaces in a pattern like this:
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhIw2.png)

My code for counting down and up:

```
def f(n):
if n==0:
    print (n)  
    return
print (n) 
f(n-1)  
print (n)
```

Comment: Your indentation is totally wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this to contrast the other answers provided here -

```py
def f(n, s = ""):
  if n <= 0:
    print(s, n)
  else:
    print(s, n)
    f(n - 1, s + " ")
    print(s, n)

f(5)
```

```
 5
  4
   3
    2
     1
      0
     1
    2
   3
  4
 5
```

The program could be further simplified, if desired -

```py
def f(n, s = ""):
  print(s, n)
  if n > 0:
    f(n - 1, s + " ")
    print(s, n)

f(5)
```

Default parameter `s` could be an integer instead of a string, if desired -

```py
def f(n, s = 0):
  print(" "*s, n)
  if n > 0:
    f(n - 1, s + 1)
    print(" "*s, n)

f(5)
```

Output is the same.

---

`print` adds a space between the printed arguments. To remove this, we can print a single formatted value -

```py
def f(n, s = ""):
  print(s + str(n))          # <- single value
  if n > 0:
    f(n - 1, s + " ")
    print(s + str(n))        # <- single value
```

Or you can use a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) -

```py
def f(n, s = ""):
  print(f"{s}{n}")     # <- formatted string
  if n > 0:
    f(n - 1, s + " ")
    print(f"{s}{n}")   # <- formatted string
```

Comment: yep this works but there shouldnt be a space before the first and last number

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 5 #you can take any value, it will be actually taken from the user
def f(n):
    global a
    if n == 0:
        print(' '*a + str(n))
        return
    print(' '*(a-n), + str(n))
    f(n-1)
    print(' '*(a-n), + str(n))
a = int(input())
f(a)
```

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of **prohibited to use if functions**. A recursion has a base case and a recursive case... so it is necessary to use ***if***.

Comment: you can print spaces by multiplying

Comment: let me make the changes... but remember... this feature is only for python.

Comment: might i add that its not necessarily always 5 for the value of n, it can be anything from 0 to 10. I just noticed that the code you sent relied on 5 being the value to be inputted for n.

Comment: OK... I will have to change it again... wait bro

Comment: let me know whether this works perfectly or not @RubenCapuli

Comment: it works! but the number before the first input has a space where it shouldnt have any.

Comment: can you kindly show what output you are getting? by the way, which country you are from bro? @RubenCapuli

Comment: I executed this program and it was perfectly fine

Comment: if inputted 5, there is a space before the first 5 and the last 5 as seen here when there should be none https://imgur.com/eptIh0k

Comment: Check now @RubenCapuli and tell me if it works fine. Also tell me which country you belong to.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not exactly what you need. But it gives you an idea :)

As you can see it is based on @Samudra Ganguly's answer

```
def f(n,x):
    if n < 0:
        return
    p(n,x-n)
    f(n-1,x)
    if n !=0:
        p(n,x-n)
    
def p(m,x):
    print(" ", end = "")
    if x>0:
        p(m,x-1)
    else:
        print(m, end = "\n")
    
f(8,8)
```

[image]

Also you can change the function like this:

```
k=4;

def f(n):
    if n < 0:
        return
    p(n,k-n)
    f(n-1)
    if n !=0:
        p(n,k-n)
    
def p(m,x):
    print(" ", end = "")
    if x>0:
        p(m,x-1)
    else:
        print(m, end = "\n")
    
f(k)
```